# Time formatting in watchOS Complication

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I want to display a timer as part of a complication. The timer should only display minutes and hours. For this purpose I have created a `CLKRelativeDateTextProvider` and passed the corresponding units as an array to the initializer. So my current attempt looks like the following:

```
func currentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication) async -> CLKComplicationTimelineEntry? {
    let relativeProvider = CLKRelativeDateTextProvider(date: Date(), style: .timer, units: [.hour, .minute])
    let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCornerStackText(
        innerTextProvider: relativeProvider,
        outerTextProvider: CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Test")
    )
    
    return CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work right, because seconds are displayed alongside minutes and hours.
So for example the following screenshot was taken at the moment where the timer displayed 29 seconds.
[image]

Do you have any idea how I could achieve a format like H:mm to display only the hour and minute at every point in time (29 seconds should be displayed as 0:00). I don't understand why the passed units are being ignored.

Thanks for your help :-)...

PS: I'm also open to other approaches like working with SwiftUI to get the time properly displayed but all my attempts in this direction haven't been successful so far.

Comment: Sounds like http://www.openradar.me/35241091

Comment: @Shadowrun Thanks for your comment. It looks indeed quite similar.